# Как закрыть зависшую горутину?

Tags: golang

У меня есть определенный код, который запускается в горутине, а именно:

```
func reader(conn *telnet.Conn, nextReadSize int) (string, error) {
    nextBytes := make([]byte, nextReadSize)
    _, err := conn.Read(nextBytes)
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }
    return string(nextBytes), nil
}
```

Он отрабатывает так как положено, но если переменная `nextReadSize` будет больше чем размер текста готового к считыванию, то горутина ожидает вывод дальше, до тех пор пока `nextBytes` не будет заполнен весь.

Как сделать так, чтобы горутина закрывалась, если выполняется больше, скажем, 1 секунды?
Можно конечно, через `select` ожидать вывода в канал и каждый раз открывать новую горутину, но не слишком ли это расточительно? Я понимаю, когда одна две горутины, а когда их несколько тысяч?

Также есть вариант считывать по одному байту, но считывать лог размером в несколько тысяч строк по байту, так себе идея.

Спасибо

Comment: ну чтобы закрывалась по таймауту можно заюзать [context with cancel](https://golang.org/pkg/context/#example_WithCancel)

Comment: горутины могут быть не полноценными потоками. поэтому вопрос производительности я бы оставил на потом. а вы не пробовали сделать read и чекать на  io.EOF ?

Answer (score 1):

Работу одной гороутину в принципе нельзя принудительно остановить из другой. Если нужен механизм управления процессом завершения работы, то его нужно реализовать  отдельно. Можно использовать таймауты, контекст, передачу команды на завершения каналом или что-то еще, много вариантов. [пример](https://yourbasic.org/golang/stop-goroutine/)

Старайтесь не делать методов, которые могут работать вечно. Для длительных процессов больше подходит бесконечный цикл с выполнением задачи маленькими порциями и регулярной проверкой условия завершения работы (например отмена контекста).

```
var pigsFly = false

// процесс с неопределенным временем работы
func longProcess(ctx context.Context, params ...interface{}) {

    // канал по которому придет отмена контекста
    killed := ctx.Done()

Loop1:
    for {

        // проверка отмены контекста
        select {
        case <-killed:
            break Loop1 // завершение работы, если контекст отменен
        default:
        }

        // процесс с определенным временем работы
        time.Sleep(time.Second)
        fmt.Printf("Im alive %v\n", time.Now())

        // проверка выполнения задачи
        if pigsFly {
            fmt.Printf("Pigs fly! %v\n", time.Now())
            break Loop1
        }
    }
}
```

При таком подходе вам незачем беспокоиться, полетят ли когда-то свиньи. Вы можете передать контекст с таймаутом, и процесс завершиться после таймаута, или отменить контекст вручную в любое удобное время в другой гороутине.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте методы типа net.Conn для установки таймаутов. Таких методов три:

- Общий таймаут
- Таймаут на чтение
- Таймаут на запись

В данном случае -- вам интересна установка таймаута на чтение.

**ВНИМАНИЕ!**
Таймаут устанавливается в форме конкретного момента времени, поэтому его НАДО ВЫСТАВЛЯТЬ КАЖДЫЙ РАЗ перед КАЖДЫМ ЧТЕНИЕМ.